# Diffie-Hellman large prime number weakness. Is this concept valid? If so, how can this be remediated by end-users/admins?

Tags: encryption, attack-prevention, diffie-hellman

So I saw this blog post on [“How is NSA breaking so much crypto?”](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/haldermanheninger/how-is-nsa-breaking-so-much-crypto/). The basic idea of this blog post is this: There is an inherent weakness in Diffie-Hellman that stems from services using the same large prime number by default. Meaning, if that one default large prime number is not changed, then that becomes a potential weakness since if that default large prime number is hacked and commonly known, access to systems in which that value has not been changed becomes relatively simple.

> For the nerds in the audience, here’s what’s wrong: If a client and
>   server are speaking Diffie-Hellman, they first need to agree on a
>   large prime number with a particular form. There seemed to be no
>   reason why everyone couldn’t just use the same prime, and, in fact,
>   many applications tend to use standardized or hard-coded primes. But
>   there was a very important detail that got lost in translation between
>   the mathematicians and the practitioners: an adversary can perform a
>   single enormous computation to “crack” a particular prime, then easily
>   break any individual connection that uses that prime.

Okay, I haven’t completely bought the concept here. But assuming this article’s assumptions are true—that usage of similar default prime numbers in various Diffie-Hellman deployments invites an inherent weakness—then my question is this:

**If deployment laziness—as marked by providing a default large prime number—is the primary attack surface of a Diffie-Hellman implementation, then what can be done by average end users and systems administrators—if anything—to pre-emptively neutralize this issue?**

I might be treading a bit into the deep end of my abilities of understanding the building blocks of encryption, but is the concept of a weakness presented in that article something that would require—for example—certificate authorities to issue new root certificates? And unless that happens, a commonly used default Diffie-Hellman large prime number vulnerability would still be a concern and potential vulnerability?

Or is the whole assumption of that blog post based on a [“thruthy”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) analysis that could be considered to be akin to [the panic surrounding Y2K bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) that—while a valid concern on some level—never really manifested itself on a scale large enough to justify the panic associated with the concern?

Comment: My understanding is that as far as TLS is concerned, if the cipher suite uses ephemeral Diffie-Hellman there would be little to no effect as the server can choose the DH params when the connection is being negotiated and can thus pick a different prime for the group order.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use any cipher suite involving DH on a prime group smaller than 2048 or even better 3072 bits. That's what you can do as a sysadmin...

The EFF has practical advice : https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2015/10/how-to-protect-yourself-from-nsa-attacks-1024-bit-DH